# How to fit 15 fields into a 400px by 510px form

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile

I'm currently dealing with a form that has many fields, and I am trying to fit them all nicely within a box that is 400px in height and 510px in width. Im pretty noobish when it comes to editing advanced CSS (this is advanced for me).

Would love it if someone could figure this one out for me! I'm not trying to get this done for me, but rather if someone did it or explained how to do it, it would really help me learn how to do it myself.

- I do not have access to the html
- I'm pulling the stylesheet from another server which I also do not have access to
- I need 15 form fields to fit (neatly) within that 400x510px space

CSS:

```
#qw {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #transparent;
    border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font: 14px/20px sylfaen, garamond, 'urw palladio l', georgia, serif;
}
#qw #qw_header {
    background-image:;
    width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
}
#qw label {
    display: none;
}
#qw fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
#qw fieldset legend {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#qw fieldset input, #qw fieldset select {
    width: 93%;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-top-color: #777;
    border-bottom-color: #ddd;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    height: 18px;
}
#qw fieldset select {
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;
}
#qw .qw_personal_header {
    text-align: center;
}
#qw .qw_personal_header:before {
    content:'You';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
}
#qw .qw_personal:after {
    clear: both;
}
#qw .qw_vehicle_header {
    text-align: center;
    clear:both;
}
#qw .qw_vehicle_header:before {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 16px;
    content:' Car';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
}
#qw .qw_first_name, #qw .qw_last_name, #qw .qw_zip_code, #qw .qw_city, #qw .qw_state, #qw .qw_phone, #qw .qw_email {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 5px;
}
#qw .qw_monthly_income, #qw .qw_vehicle_year, #qw .qw_vehicle_make, #qw .qw_vehicle_model, #qw .qw_vehicle_mileage, #qw .qw_vehicle_owned {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 5px;
}
#qw .qw_vehicle_owned {
    width: 93%;
}
#qw .submit {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#qw .submit input {
    background:url cursor:pointer;
    height: 46px;
    width: 297px !important;
    font-size: 0px;
    border: none;
}
#qw .qw_legal {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    line-height: 12px;
}
#qw .qw_legal a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#qw .submit input {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: If you know of one sure, though if someone were to do some of it I could view the adjustments and maybe figure it out :)

Comment: This seems like a great example of "too broad".

Comment: Is it too broad? The CSS is there, and so is the objective. If I should include something more please let me know.

Comment: I see css, but I'm not seeing the html to apply it to?

Comment: @Dr.Tenma you should probably supply the HTML to narrow the scope of the question…

Comment: I do apologize, I do not have access to the html.. I'm pulling the stylesheet from another server which I also do not have access to, I guess maybe a better way of putting this is... I need 15 form fields to fit (neatly) within that 400x510px space. The main difficulty I am having is the neatly part, because im getting lost while adjusting all of those fields :(

Comment: So what *do* you have access to?

Comment: that's it really, I can give a shot of where Im trying to fit the form if that helps? Though I thought 15 fields neatly in a 400x510px space would have been understandable.

Comment: Please post the form(html code) so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/Jbj2h/

using bootstrap 3.1: http://getbootstrap.com

CSS:

```
.form-box {
    width: 510px !important;
    height: 400px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    background-color: White;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}
body {
    background-color: Gainsboro;
}
.form-box .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-box textarea {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-box">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="awesome">Awesome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="awesome" placeholder="Enter text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="2" placeholder="stuff"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Go!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find with css fitting things on a form can be a bit tricky. My advice would be to avoid using floats and clearfixes where you can and instead stick to your width=__%
When using the width however one thing that trips me up is that this includes the margin and padding as well, so why it might make sense to have two items side by side at 50%, it doesn't often work out that way.
Another tip I use when doing css like this is to inspect it in the browser using development tools (In most you access this by right clicking and selecting "inspect element"). This way you can modify your css code as much as you like until your happy with it to try it in your code proper, as well as seeing the boundaries of the margins, content and padding.

Comment: Thank you for the tips sir! When I inspect the field sets this is the part of my css that I am able to edit:#qw fieldset input, #qw fieldset select {
 width: 93%;
 border: 1px solid #bbb;
 border-top-color: #777;
 border-bottom-color: #ddd;
 padding: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 height: 18px; from my newbie perspective I understand that it is letting me edit the actual fields... What I don't know is how to adjust them and make them fit in the sized box I mentioned. I guess I dont know the proper parameters to make it look pretty.

Comment: Actually... so far I've figured out that floating all the fields to the left splits the fields so they are lined up next to each other... though I do not understand why? I'm guessing ill have to significantly decrease the height of the fields, but it will look very poor if I do this.

Comment: No worries(for the record I'm not a sir I'm a ma'am). When you inspect element you can edit what is already there. If you click just below or at the top in the in-line style part you add new things too to see how they look. So you can play around with the heights and widths on the page to see how they look in real time.

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/r3gw7/

Concept fiddle, makes use of

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Anything within "someforms" will be 'all nicely within a box that is x in height and x in width', no?

Comment: But why do I want a scrolling form?! Make the contents in a nice box, not the box in a nice (scroll) box. (Or, at least that's what I think the question means)

Comment: Thanks John, I see what you did there, my issue is that all those fields will be within a responsive form so a scroll wont be very friendly on a smaller device. I appreciate the input though, it is a solution nonetheless.

Comment: I mean it's just one answer that seems to point him in A direction, possibly the right one. Maybe you can take this time to come up with a better solution? I know I can't ;D